# How to do remote profiling via YourKit command line?

Tags: java, java-8, yourkit

I am trying to do remote profiling (since I don't have access to UI on the remote machine) via command line as mentioned in the below link

https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/command_line_tool.jsp

I have started the application with profiler agent and I have done a CPU sampling.

```
root@platform1:/tmp/tuk/YourKit-JavaProfiler# java -jar lib/yjp-controller-api-redist.jar localhost 10002 start-sampling
CPU sampling started
root@platform1:/tmp/tuk/YourKit-JavaProfiler# java -jar lib/yjp-controller-api-redist.jar localhost 10002 stop-cpu-profiling
CPU profiling stopped
```

Can some let me know

1. Where the sampling data is saved and how can I analyze it next?
2. Is it possible to transfer the sampling date to my local so that I can analyze it via yourkit UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered [yourkit forum](https://www.yourkit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42097). Posting the answer below

> > Where the sampling data is saved and how can I analyze it next?
>
> Please capture a snapshot after (or right before) stopping CPU
> profiling by using the command "capture-performance-snapshot".
>
> > Is it possible to transfer the sampling date to my local so that I can
> > analyze it via yourkit UI?
>
> Yes. Please transfer the snapshot file to your local machine for
> analysis. Snapshot files are created in /Snapshots by
> default, see https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/snapshot_dir.jsp